# What does this humor mean?

Tags: humor

Why is this caption funny?

"Faster! By God, you will earn that tip yet!"

[Source](http://www.condenaststore.com/-sp/Faster-By-God-you-ll-earn-that-tip-yet-New-Yorker-Cartoon-Prints_i10456534_.htm)

Since this is about American humor, I'd appreciate an answer from Americans.

Comment: Ummmmmm . . . can we see the cartoon?

Comment: Sorry.  I was blind on that one.

Comment: Class distinction LIVE ON! Even in America.

Comment: Seeking an explanation of a *New Yorker* cartoon caption is often a fools errand. They can be just as incomprehensible to us Americans as they are to foreigners.

Comment: My answer: it's not really very funny. Bellboys normally use those cart thingies to transport the guests' bags from the lobby up to the rooms (and back down), but here, a very distinguished-looking, middle-aged gentleman has apparently ordered the bellboy to give him a ride in it instead, like a child getting a ride in a supermarket trolley. Since he apparently considers this part of the bell it's job, he is making him work hard for his tip by running faster, faster.

Comment: I read it as satire of American tipping culture, but I'm probably reading too much into it.

Comment: @user867 It's more of a satire of the expectations of the wealthy clientele of hotels than the tipping culture *per se*.

Comment: @DavidM Ah, you're the author! You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @user867 Perhaps you'd prefer if I posted:  "I believe it to be a satire of the expectations of the wealthy clientele of hotels than the tipping culture *per se*."  That said, as an American tipper, I'd say if it were a parody of American tipping culture, he'd have stiffed the bellboy after the ride.

Comment: It turns out that this is not a joke that is particular to English language. Also, as others have said, New Yorker cartoons are hardly ever outright funny. They are very dead-pan.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as a speaker of American English I will say:  It's not *that* funny.

But, in any case, it's a rich guy who is being raced around on a hotel bird-cage cart.  And, he is telling the bellhop that he has to keep servicing him to earn his tip.

I cannot speak to why it's funny, because it really isn't.  But, the joke is that the bellhop has to race the guy around in order to earn a tip.

Comment: @username901345 Yes. The construction "You'll [verb] yet" means "You'll eventually [verb]", presumably if you keep working towards it.

Comment: @username901345: The artwork on that cartoon looks modern, but the words (and the "humour") would be more appropriate a century or two ago. That's why David says it's not *that* funny - times have moved on, and today we actually have to struggle to see the humour at all. We're certainly not likely to *laugh* at it. The "funniest" aspect to me is the archaic phrasing - we would rarely use appended "yet" in that way today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well said.

Comment: @David: Well, I think your own answer had already robustly defended your countrymen (assuming you *are* American - your profile is silent on the matter) from the implied slur that OP's cartoon might tickle the typical American's ribs. I'm biased, so I obviously think *humour* is much funnier than *humor*, but I'm sure you're not *that* easily amused as a nation. Anyway, the question has done *some* good - apart from giving me the chance to pun away with the worst of them, I now know what a *bird cage cart* is. (All joking aside, I really *do* thank you for that! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers In order:  Yes, I'm American, yet, I consider myself a fluent speaker of English despite this obvious handicap!  I, too, enjoy *humour* as well as humor (my Mac does not, as it tried to autocorrect!).  And, lastly, the *bird cage cart*, I was told that was the name for it by no less an authority than a hotel bellman.  The name fit, and I've kept it.  (Do a google images search for bird cage cart.)